# SQL Row_Number() and Linq record count different

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, sql-server-2012, row-number

I have two bits of code doing basically the same thing but the results are different. I am trying to get the index number of a record from an ordered list in the database, and then skip/take some results.

Linq method:

```
int index = db.users.OrderByDescending(o => o.TotalScore)
              .ToList()
              .FindIndex(f => f.UserId == User.UserId); 
               // returns 557
```

SQL method:

```
WITH IndexedUsers AS (
  SELECT UserId, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalScore desc) AS 'RowNumber'
  FROM [User]  
) 
SELECT RowNumber
FROM IndexedUsers 
WHERE UserId = @userId
//Returns 559
```

Stumped at the difference here. I dont want to be calling ToList on the user collection from the database, i am just using it for testing purposes. I would expect the results to be 1 out with the FindIndex method being 0 based. Any ideas why the values aren't the same?

Comment: Is TotalScore unique in your data set?  If not, that might be the reason.

Comment: No TotalScore isnt unique, there are lots of duplicates, which is why i would expect the row number to be further apart, not just 1 (being 0 based) if that was the reason.

Comment: SQL Server makes no guarantee about how records are ordered in this case, so why do you expect them to be farther apart?

Comment: Is there a way i can make the resulting row number match up to what linq is doing then? as i use skip/take using linq based on the row number i get back.

Comment: Add another order by that would make the order unique.  The close the order by is to being unique, the closer the row numbers should be.  What you are asking works best when ordered by a primary or unique key.

Comment: Also notice that `FindIndex` is 0 based while `ROW_NUMBER` is ` based.